# why is matplotlib unresponsive?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

when using ipython notebook with

```
ipython notebook --pylab
```

if i am running a cpu intensive code then the old matplotlib figures become unresponsive. Is there any way to run matplotlib on a separate thread. I have already tried ion() command but nothing seems to work

I know this is pretty basic, but I can't find a simple command to do so!!

Comment: Can you check to see if your plots are actually open in the background? If they are, then IPython will seem unresponsive, but it's actually just waiting for you to close your plot. The way around this is to use `ipython notebook --pylab inline` to have IPython plot them in the notebook.

Comment: i dont want inline plots! I want to do zoom etc on the plots, so I really really want the matplotlib interface. So lets say I plotted 10 plots...and after those plots in other cells some intensive code is running. Why can't I play around with the already plotted plots. I seem to get that mac red wheel turning!. I can choose the plot...but can't do anything else with them!

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to use pylab for plotting in IPython notebooks since it "populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib" (and e.g., overwrite Python functions like `sum` by the NumPy equivalent). I think a better approach is to use the

%matplotlib inline

magic function and then import pyplot and numpy separately to make it clear what functions you are using

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

This way, you can specifically use, e.g., use the NumPy sum via

`np.sum(my_numpy_array)` and `sum(my_python_list)` (which makes sense performance-wise for large array or list objects.

for plotting, you can then use

`plt.plot(my_data)`

Comment: that still doesn't answer my question. The calculations are bulky but I plot just the summary data....or 20-30 points. Then another heavy calc and then another summary of 20-30 points. I would like to have a responsive matplotlib while my notebook is crunching other cells